# How do I stop the AWS CLI evaluating/following URLs and using the response instead?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When using `aws ssm put-parameter`, with a URL in value it follows and puts the response from API.

I want the exact value of the HTTP endpoint I provide e.g.

> https://supersecure.com

not the response from the endpoint e.g.

> `<html>xyz</html>"`

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name /example --value https://endpointthatreturnsaresponsee --type String
```

How do I stop the AWS CLI following and capturing the response of URLs?

Answer (score 6):

Set [`cli_follow_urlparam`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#general-options) to `false`:

```
aws configure set cli_follow_urlparam false
```